# Gradle Eclipse Plugin only half-working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to achieve the following between Eclipse and Gradle:

- Allow Gradle to handle 100% of my local build logic; only use Eclipse as an IDE for syntax highlighting, refactoring, etc. Every time I wish to build my app I want to drop into a command line and run a Gradle build invocation from there.
- I want the `dependencies` closure of my `build.gradle` file to be the sole location for configuring 3rd party dependencies; every time I make a change to this closure (adding/removing a dependency/JAR), I want Eclipse to automagically "see" this change and adjust my project's classpath accordingly

I installed the [Gradle-Eclipse Integration plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44) and then I followed [this tutorial](http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/java-project-gradle-eclipse-integration-example) for configuring it correctly.

First I ran:

```
gradle clean build
```

And then I added:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

To my `build.gradle`, and then ran:

```
gradle eclipse
```

I saw a lot of output, the tail end of which is:

```
gradle eclipse
:myapp:eclipseClasspath
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2-sources.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111-sources.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1-sources.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0-sources.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.3.7/groovy-all-2.3.7-sources.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0-sources.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1-sources.jar
:myapp:eclipseJdt
:myapp:eclipseProject
:myapp:eclipse
```

I then opened my `.classpath` file and see that its been correctly updated with all the transitive dependencies defined in my `dependencies` closure back inside `build.gradle`.

However, there is not visual indication inside Eclipse that anything is wired correctly. With Ivy or Maven, you usally get something like a `Ivy Repository Manager` or `Maven Dependency Library` that automatically changes anytime you modify `ivy.xml` or `pom.xml`.

**Most importantly**, this just doesn't seem to be working! As you see above, Apache Commons Lang 3 is a dependency, but when I try to add `org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils` to a Groovy source file, Eclipse can't find it. I have already tried restarting Eclipse to see if that shook any bugs out.

**Am I just not using this plugin correctly, or does it just not work?** Using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.6.0.RELEASE here, which is based on Eclipse Luna 4.4.

Comment: Reverseing the previous edit because I do believe this is an issue with either the Gradle-Eclipse Integration plugin (an Eclipse plugin) or the Eclipse Gradle plugin (a Gradle plugin).

Comment: You'd either use the IDE side plugin and import the Gradle build, *or* run `gradle eclipse` and open the generated Eclipse project. `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` should be added in both cases. Dependency management usually works just fine. Perhaps try with Java source code, to rule out a problem with the IDE Groovy plugin.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser - however a very disconcerting question: I started from a barebones Java template (`src/main/java`, `src/main/test`) and a simple `build.gradle` that only declared 1 dependency (Guice) inside it. I ran `gradle eclipse` and this time it worked perfectly.  **However**, I then added Guava as a dependency in `build.gradle`, re-ran `gradle eclipse` and nothing updated in Eclipse (even after refreshing the project and restarting). So **is `gradle eclipse` just meant to be ran once at project startup?!** If so, what can I use to manage deps moving forward?

Comment: If you use the `gradle eclipse` approach, you'll have to run it after every change to `build.gradle` that affects the IDE, and then refresh the IDE project (e.g. select the project in Project Explorer and press F5). I've never had any problems with this.

Comment: Agree with @PeterNiederwieser. What you are doing seems to be ok. You can run gradle eclipse as many times as you need. Refreshing should work (sometimes you need to retry, mostly if you have many projects. Have you selected the "Build automatically" flag in the Project menu?

Comment: You can also enable the Eclipse auto refresh feature within your "Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or polling".